# Run artifactory on browser

Tags: linux, browser, artifactory

I installed artifactory on linux server. I want to know how to check whether it is properly installed.

Secondly, I want to use it's user interface on google chrome. From where I can get SERVER_DOMAIN and PORT number for it's url from installed files on server?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague.

How did you installed it (ZIP, RPM, Docker, Deb...)?

Which database you used (default, Oracle, MySQL etc..)? You can see if the server is up and running by running the following REST API from the machine you have installed it on:

curl -iuadmin:password localhost:8081/artifactory/api/system/ping

Regarding the IP, this can be checked by running 'ifconfig' on the linux server and get the IP of that machine.

Artifactory by default is running on port 8081, unless you changed it.

It seems that you will need to follow the basic installation wiki:
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Installing+Artifactory

Comment: Thanks @Ariel , for your reply. I installed it manually by it's zip file and i am using default (derby) database.

I edited the port numbers in server.xml as follows:

<Server port="8017" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">

    <Service name="Catalina">
        <Connector port="8082"/>

                <Connector port="8020" protocol="AJP/1.3"/>
        <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="172.21.163.62">
            <Host name="172.21.163.62" appBase="webapps"/>
        </Engine>

    </Service>
</Server>

Now, i want to know which port number i have to use?

Comment: And after running curl -iuadmin:password localhost:8081/artifactory/api/system/ping command, it gives :
curl: (7) Failed connect to localhost:8081; Connection refused
What is it means?

Comment: In the first comment you wrote that you changed the port to 8082 "<Connector port="8082"/>" you should run the curl command to the same port:

 curl -iuadmin:password localhost:8082/artifactory/api/system/ping

Comment: thank you again for the correction but it is giving same output i.e  (7) Failed connect to localhost:8082; Connection refusedwith 8082 also.

Comment: Have you started Artifactory? 

If yes: 
Are you running it from the Artifactory machine?

If yes:
What do you see in the $ARTIFACTORY_HOME/logs/artifactory.log

Comment: Yes, i have started it. I installed artifactory on server and i am running it there only.

Comment: ARTIFACTORY_HOME/logs/artifactory.log has USER INFO, HOST INFO, ARTIFACTORY INFO and JAVA SYSTEM INFO... If you were asking for something specific, please tell.

Comment: Sir i followed that installation process only and installed it on server but i have been facing problems in starting its UI on google chrome. I don't know what to write on the place of server domain and port no. I am confused.

Comment: What error do you see in the $ARTIFACTORY_HOME/logs/artifactory.log, if no errors there look for the $ARTIFACTORY_HOME/tomcat/logs/catalina.out and $ARTIFACTORY_HOME/tomcat/logs/localhost.log and see if you can see any errors there. 
If no errors appear in the logs you should be able to reach Artifactory using (once again only when your browser is on the same machine as Artifactory, if not get the Artifactory machine IP and replace the localhost) 'http://localhost:8082/artifactory'

Comment: No errors in artifactory.log. catalina.out is giving a WARNING: Failed to process JAR [jar:file:/jpmcenv1/jpmcenv1/Prasoon_artifactory/ARTIFACTORY_HOME/tomcat/webapps/artifactory/WEB-INF/lib/jersey-server-1.12.jar!/] for TLD files.
For this i replaced the jar after downloading it but problem persists.

In localhost.log i found an error that is:
SEVERE: Exception starting filter WicketFilter
java.lang.NullPointerException.

Can you please help me for this? Thanks.

Comment: And i installed it on as server whose IP is 172.21.279.56... So i am using https://172.21.279.56:8082/artifactory.. Is this correct? I hope it is since I am a beginner for artifactory and linux both that is why getting so much silly issues. Kindly help me.

Comment: Can you share the output of 'ifconfig' command here?
Also, can you please confirm that you are not running it inside a docker container?

Comment: Sir i installed it on a remote server using Putty for login into the server. The IP of the server is 172.21.279.56 which i already mentioned above. And no, i am not running it inside docker container. The process i used for installation is manual, copied tar on remote server, extract it, copy the artifactory.war into tomcat and running it by sh artifactory.sh command. 

While executing artifactory.sh, the output is Artifactory started succesfully in 3.239 seconds on remote server. But after that if I tried to open it on google chrome, it gives error :

This site can’t be reached.

Comment: Ok, now we are getting somewhere.
I've mentioned it several times, please run the localhost command from the Artifactory machine. 
Now, can you try running ping from your machine to 172.21.279.56 and write what is the output?

Comment: This is ouput when i ping server from my local machine's cmd :
Pinging 172.21.279.56 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 172.21.279.56: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=61
Reply from 172.21.279.56: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=61
Reply from 172.21.279.56: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=61
Reply from 172.21.279.56: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=61

Ping statistics for 172.21.279.56:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms

Comment: Thanks for all your help. My issues have been solved and artifactory UI started succesfully on browser. Thank you very much.

Comment: I already upvoted it but my reputation is less than 15, so it is not displaying publically.